# How to join text files together horizontally

Tags: python, object, syntax

In my code i am using pygame and i am reading text files into maps. I am trying to create a long map that randomly joins my map segment text files together in a horizontal way to create a long map. How would i join multiple text files together and write the result to a new file.

Lets say text file 1 is equal to the below:

```
1111111111
100000000
100000000
1111111111
```

Lets say text file 2 is equal to the below:

```
1111111111
1000011111
1000000000
1111111111
```

And the result could look like this:

```
11111111111111111111
1000000001000011111
1000000001000000000
11111111111111111111
```

Thanks for the help and if anyone would like to check out my full project it is [here](https://github.com/Seaste0809/Platform-Game-Version-1.2/tree/main)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to do this. Here's another way:

```
filenames = (r"map1.txt", r"map2.txt")

# Each line from every file will be stored in a list as strings
lines = []
for filename in filenames:
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line_num, line in enumerate(f):
            # You cannot index into a list if it doesn't exist, so
            # you need to append to it first
            if line_num == len(lines):
                lines.append(line.strip())
            else:
                lines[line_num] += line.strip()

# This transforms the list into a single string, with a newline between every item
map_str = "\n".join(line for line in lines)

print(map_str)
```

Output:

```
11111111111111111111
1000000001000011111
1000000001000000000
11111111111111111111
```

By the way, are you sure you don't need each row of the map to be the same length? Some are 10 while others are 9.

Answer (score 0):

This logic works when the number of lines in both files are same.

```
with open("file1") as file1, open("file2") as file2:
    file1_lines= file1.readlines()
    file2_lines = file2.readlines()
result = [line[0] + line[1] for line in zip(file1_lines, file2_lines)]
with open("outfile", "w") as outfile:
     outfile.write("\n".join(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

- Input files: x.txt, y.txt
- Output file: z.txt

**Code**

```
with open("x.txt") as xh, open('y.txt') as yh, open("z.txt","w") as zh:
    for x, y in zip(xh, yh):
        zh.write(x.rstrip() + y)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var1 = """
    1111111111
    100000000
    100000000
    1111111111
    """
    var2 = """
    1111111111
    1000011111
    1000000000
    1111111111
    """
    var1 = [x.strip() for x in var1.split("\n") if x]
    var2 = [x.strip() for x in var2.split("\n") if x]

    for x, y in zip(var1, var2):
        print(f"{x}{y}")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].

Answer (score 0):

```
# Read files
f1 = open('file1.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
f2 = open('file2.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
# Read lines
lines1 = f1.readlines()
lines2 = f2.readlines()
# If len(file1) < len(file2) append file1 zeros and vice versa.
lines1.extend([0,] * (len(lines2) - len(lines1)))
lines2.extend([0,] * (len(lines1) - len(lines2)))
# remove \n from file1
lines1 = [x[:-2] for x in lines1]
# print result XD
print(''.join(list(map(lambda x: x[0] + "{0:1}".format(x[1]), zip(lines1, lines2)))))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].